# google.maps.DirectionsRenderer : How to render all stop points in one map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a map that shows direction of shuttle following are the map and direction initialisation code

```
var centerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.942799,138.553365);
  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: centerLatlng,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
  },
  panControl:true,
  streetViewControl: false,
    OverviewMapControlOptions:
    {
      opened: true
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-guide-google-map"),  myOptions);
```

Following is the Display Direction

```
function DisplayDirection(directionList){
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      markerOptions: {
        visible:false
      }
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    //Request 0
    var increaseSize = 7;
    var index =0;
    var theoryCurrentEndIndex = index + increaseSize;
    var maxmimumIndex = directionList.length-1;
    var origin = directionList[index];
    var destination = theoryCurrentEndIndex < maxmimumIndex?directionList[theoryCurrentEndIndex]:directionList[maxmimumIndex];
    var actualCurrentEndIndex = theoryCurrentEndIndex < maxmimumIndex?theoryCurrentEndIndex: maxmimumIndex;
    var waypoints = new Array();
    if(actualCurrentEndIndex-index>1) {
      for(var i=index+1;i<actualCurrentEndIndex;i++) {
        waypoints.push(

            {
              location:directionList[i],
              stopover:true}

        );
      }
    }

    var request = {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      waypoints : waypoints,
      provideRouteAlternatives:false,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    }

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      }
    }) ;
}
```

How can I reset the LatLongBounds to show all the stop points and centre the map

Comment: I don't see any LatLongBounds object in your code. What so you want to "reset"?

Comment: I have not used LatLongBounds, as it doesn't seems to work. All I am trying to do is get all the stop-points to appear in one map screen